# AEM Translation is not working

Tags: translation, aem

I am new to AEM and facing issue with Translation. I am creating a multilingual site following [documentation](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-2/administer/sites/translation.html) for translation.I have not written any custom code. I did the following things.

1. Selecting the Microsoft built in translator.
2. Selecting EN publication as source and Es as target publication.
3. Selecting i18n dictionary/Pages for Translation.
4. Starting and completing Translation from Translation Job[image]
5. browsing the page
   [image]

It's showing the English content.

Translation is completed successfully but it's not reflecting in the target page. Is there any blog/article for translation?
I am using Microsoft default translation service

Comment: Please add the exact issue you are having along with any code snippets or solutions you have tried.

Comment: Which version of AEM are you using? Also, make sure the language codes are in lower case en, es.

Comment: I am using AEM 6.2. Yes the languages are in lower case

Comment: Hi Manish were you able to fix your issue, I am having the similar issue